# lower bound for factorials product

Tags: factorial

For $n$ positive integer, let $F(n) = 1! × 2! × 3! × 4! × \cdots × n!$, product of factorial(i) for $i$ in $[1\ldots n]$.

Let $G(n) = \{i \in [1\ldots n],\text{ such that }n\mid F(i)\}$.

It is obvious that n belongs to G(n) that makes it a non empty set.

Can we find min(G(n)) without using brute-force? is there any mathematical result based on this or any specific theorem?

for eg: $n=4$ answer is $3$
$F(1) = 1! = 1$ , not divisible by $4$
$F(2) = 1! × 2! = 2$ , not divisible by $4$
$F(3) = 1! × 2! × 3! = 12$ , divisible by $4$
$F(4) = 1! × 2! × 3! × 4! = 288$ , divisible by $4$
So $G(4) = {3, 4}$.

I was thinking if we can use prime factorisation of $n$ here somehow!

Comment: The minimal value is always $1$... or I'm getting the question completely wrong.

Comment: @vonbrand: n should divide F(i)...look at given example again

Comment: Irrelevant, you are asking for the *smallest* element of $G(i)$, and that one is always 1.

Comment: @vonbrand No, $G(n) = \{ i : 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n, n \mid F(i)\}$ only contains those $i \leqslant n$ such that $F(i)$ is a multiple of $n$.